# How to refresh/reload a parent component onclick of child component submit button in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, angular6

My parent component ts file contains this code:

```
 openNewModal(): void {
    this.$modal.show(CategoryAddModalComponent)
        .subscribe(r => {
   });
   location.reload();
  }
```

My child component html:

```
    <form action="">
    <label>Enter Category</label>
        <input name="cate" type="text">
        <input name="category" type="text">
        <button class="common-btn btn-cancel" (click)="modal.hide();l>Cancel</button>
    <button class="common-btn btn" type="submit" (click)="fun_addcategory()">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

So using this openNewModal() function Im calling my child component model. Now On submit of my child component I need to reload my parent component file.  If I try to call location.reload in this function, my child component is getting reloaded. But I need to reload parent component. Can somebody please guide me how to do this?

Comment: What is your purpose of reloading parent component? If you want to change the UI state, then there are several other ways to do it. ` location.reload` is not a good choice in your case.

Comment: In Single Page Applications you do not reload the entire app or location, you change the component data and the change detection will rerender your templates. If you add more code and explain a bit more we probably can help you.

Comment: @ArpitMeena Onloading of parent component Im making a http call to display some contents. Also after adding some contents in child component, making a http call to post the content in server. after posting I need to display the same content which was posted via child component in the parent component file. Right now ater refreshing the page manually, content is displaying. So I need to reload it via some function

Answer (score 3):

No need to Reload the page

> Use ChangeDetectorRef to detect changes manually inside parent

Example:
**parent.ts**

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular.core';

constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef){}

ngOnInit(){
this.service.susbscribe((data)=>{
 this.data=data;
//detect the change manually using 
this.cdr.detectChanges();
//Checks this view and its children. 
local change detection checks

})}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please explain this code? @Chellappan

Comment: changeDetecorRef is service which is use to detect changes in the angular app. Inject the changeDetectorRef inside your parent component contructor then use detectChanges() method to detect changes manually inside where you want to detect changes

Comment: I am getting this error:  error TS2339: Property 'service' does not exist on type 'ParentComponent'.

Comment: error TS2339: Property 'service' does not exist on type 'ParentComponent'.

Comment: i have give example you need to use your service call method

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an addition flag to skip location changes like this
'''
this.router.navigate(['parentComponent', id, type], {skipLocationChange: true});
'''